# Migrate from tfs on prem to visualstudio.com fails with error OH-SCM-009 / TF14092

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

i'm trying to migrate my tfs on prem to visualstudio.com. But after a while working well (126/464 Changesets), it stops with this error:

`OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. TF14092: The item $/xyz/xyz/xyz/xyz.sln cannot be changed. A parent of this item has a pending delete which must be checked in first.
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.OIMSCMAdapter.sync(OIMSCMAdapter.java:371)`

I already tried this on two different Computers, and it always stops with this changeset. A retry of it doesn't work either.

How can i fix it?

Regards,

Alex

Comment: Hi. This is a standard TFS error when some change is tried to be applied on an item which already has pending changes. Can you please send us your logs located at <installation-path>/logs and also a screenshot of the changeset here in question from your Source TFS , which would highlight pictorially the ChangeTypes over the file.

Comment: Mail id : ovsmu@opshub.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else facing this issue.
This was an issue for a situation where conflict used on come on a file whose some parent is already deleted. And when this is done in TFS, the TFS Server automatically discards the changes post the deletion. 
Thus, OpsHub Utility now handles such cases. This has been resolved in the v1.1.0.004 and will be available for public in Mid-December.